# SQLite3 Min and Max values with thier respective timestamp

Tags: sqlite, lua

`db:exec [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fivmin_tbl (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, IDNo TEXT, time TIME, date DATE, A0 FLOAT, A1 FLOAT, A2 FLOAT, A3 FLOAT, tipper INTEGER, voltage FLOAT)]`]

I created the table above and if I want to read the Maximum and Minimum values for A0, A1, A2 and A3, and their respective timestamps from the above table. How do I do that using SQLite3

I tried the following based on the code I got from the net.

```
local query = string.format([[SELECT MIN(A0) AS min_valueA0, MAX(A0) AS max_valueA0, 
                                  MIN(A1) AS min_valueA1, MAX(A1) AS max_valueA1,
                                  MIN(A2) AS min_valueA2, MAX(A2) AS max_valueA2, 
                                  MIN(A3) AS min_valueA3, MAX(A3) AS max_valueA3,
                                  MIN(time) AS min_time, MAX(time) AS max_time FROM fivmin_tbl time >= %d AND time < %d]], StartDate, FinishtDate)
```

The Max and Min values need to be between StartDate and FinishtDate

```
local stmt = db:prepare(query)
local result = stmt:step()
```

stmt statement above cause an error

How do I change the code to make it work?

Comment: `WHERE`  is lost in `FROM fivmin_tbl WHERE time >= %d AND time < %d`

Comment: 8 separate queries; one each for the min and max of each column.